# DESFire Key Diversification AV1

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, nfc, rfid, mifare

I've implemented AES Key Diversification AV2 and now I´m wondering what is SAM AV1 and how does it work? Any one can share a link or give some informatione?

Just to share some knowledge an example for AV2:

```
/* 
         * Diversification Example: 
         * AID: 130101
         * UID: 042149BA294B80 (Big-endian: 804B29BA492104)
         * Key: F3E7E19A69AC5A9B538D4F655CCECA1C
         * 
         * Key0:        8F42B16487E36E43B6B1F3B14FCCD46D
         * firstsubKey: 1E8562C90FC6DC876D63E7629F99A85D
         * secondsubkey:3D0AC5921F8DB90EDAC7CEC53F3350BA
         * 
         *                         UID          AID  KNr  Salt            SecondsubKey
         * divInputXORKey2: 01 042149BA294B80 130101 02 6F4346 80 3D0AC5921F8DB90EDAC7CEC53F3350BA
         * encrypt: 6B5FC890EA3EDDB0C1B4B2AF5EA6A89B 958E854C9F67C68D42F21FC7FFD760AB
         * 
         * Key: 958E854C9F67C68D42F21FC7FFD760AB
         * */
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, SAM works in two modes: the X mode and the Non-X mode. The X mode requires a NXP NFC reader. In this case, the SAM send all artifacts to the PICC autonomously.

In the Non-X mode, the embedding micro controller has to handover all artifacts between SAM and the NFC reader.

You can refer the following link as well:
[Brief description of SAM](https://github.com/islog/liblogicalaccess/wiki/MIFARE-SAM-AV1-AV2-examples)

This is the official information from NXP [MIFARE SAM AV2 by NXP](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/mifare-hf/mifare-sam/mifare-sam-av2:P5DF081)

Comment: may be it´s not clear what I´m looking for. AV2 is an algorithm to diversify a key defined in AN10922 from NXP. So there is a similar process for AV1 and I want to know the algorithm for this one. For more information I will explain the AV2 algorithm in detail but don´t know how AV1 works.